# Replace words in text

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I'm programming a part of a Web application in which I replace words from a text. I used the Replace function, but I replaced text that I do not want (below put an example). Now I have implemented a function that by splitting the text into words, but when I want to replace two contiguous words in the text. Obviously, it doesn't work.

The first option:

```
var str = "iRobot Roomba balbalblablbalbla";

str.replace(/robot/gi, 'Robota');

output -> iRobota Roomba ........(fail !)
```

Second code:

```
var patterns: [ 
    {
        match: 'robot',
        replacement: 'Robota'
    },{
        match: 'ipad',
        replacement: 'tablet'
    },
    ......... more
];

var temp = str.split(' ');

var newStr = temp.map(function(el) {

    patterns.forEach(function(item) {

        if( el.search( new RegExp( '^'+item.match+'$', 'gi') ) > -1 ) {

            el = item.replacement;

            return el;
        }
    });

    return el;
});

return newStr.join(' ');
```

With this last code does not replace a two-word text, as the check only makes one. I have been searching the Internet for some solution and I have not found anything similar.

I just happen to do a split of the word to check (item.match) and if it have more than one element, create a temporal variable and check the contiguous elements, but I guess it affects performance and I do not know if there is a better and easier option.

Can anyone think of a better option?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you only want to match whole words and not sub-strings.

The solution would be to add word boundaries to your regex :

```
str.replace(/\brobot\b/gi, 'Robota');
```

This will only match whole "robot" words.

Comment: Works properly. A few minutes ago I was trying something similar, because I saw recommendations in StackOverflow, but did not escape with \\b. Thanks !! ;-)

Comment: It works, but it isn't efficient. Imagine the same thing with a large dictionary with n patterns: you need to parse the entire string n times and probably to search words that aren't even in the text!